# Refraction and reflection in special relativity

Tags: special-relativity, optics, reflection, refraction

I know that special relativity postulates that the speed of light is the same no matter the inertial reference system. Consider that we have a medium with absolute refractive index $n$ ( when the medium is stationary). If we move the medium with a speed comparable to the speed of light ( so that special relativity needs to be applied) what happens to the speed of light through that medium? Is the refractive index an invariant to Lorentz transformations? Also how does a stationary observer see the speed of light through that medium?

Comment: Fizeau's experiment showed that phase velocity of light obeys the relativistic velocity addition formula in the non-relativistic limit of the speed of the medium. However, I think Max von Laue's canonical derivation should be written in terms of events, rather than calling the speed of light in a medium $\frac{c}{n}$, as I personally don't view phase velocity (nor group velocity) as the speed of light in a medium...
Maybe you could specify what you mean by velocity of light? 
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fizeau_experiment#Derivation_in_special_relativity

Answer (score 2):

Electromagnetic response in moving media is a tricky issue for many reasons, and an exhaustive answer is tricky. I will try to show how one could approach this problem, but there may be many more additional provisos.

Prelims:

---

Firstly, electric and magnetic fields are not independent, and end up being mixed when one starts switching reference frames. You have to work with the electromagnetic tensor https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_tensor:

All latin indices are spatial ($1,2,3$ for $x,y,z$), greek indices run over temporal index as well.

$F^{\mu\nu}=-F^{\nu\mu}$

$F^{i0} = \frac{1}{c}E^i$, where $E$ is the electric field and $c$ is the speed of light.

$F^{ij} = \epsilon^{0ijs}g_{sk}B^k$, where $\epsilon^{0ijs}$ is the Levi-Civita relative tensor, $g_{\mu\nu}=diag\left(1,-1,-1,-1\right)_{\mu\nu}$ is the metric, and $B$ is the magnetic field.

We then can introduce displacement tensor:

$D^{\mu\nu}=-D^{\nu\mu}$

$D^{i0}=cD^i$, where $D$ is the electrical displacement

$D^{ij}=\epsilon^{0ijs}g_{sk}H^k$, where $H$ is the magnetic H-field

Maxwells equations are then:

$\partial_\mu D^{\mu\nu}=0$

$\partial_\mu \left(\frac{1}{2}\epsilon^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}g_{\alpha\alpha'}g_{\beta\beta'}F^{\alpha'\beta'}\right)=0$

Now we can introduce linear electromagnetic response for the material (for now without dispersion). Let it be that of an isotropic, non-magnetic, loss-less dielectric with refractive index $n$:

$D^i=\varepsilon_0 n^2 E^{i}$

$H^i=\mu_0^{-1} B^i$

Introduce tensor $\Xi^{\mu\nu}_{\alpha\beta}$ as:

$D^{\mu\nu}=\Xi^{\mu\nu}_{\alpha\beta}F^{\alpha\beta}$. For the material I have defined, I recon the correct expression of $\Xi$ is:

$\Xi^{\mu\nu}_{\alpha\beta}=\frac{\varepsilon_0}{2} u_\kappa u^\phi \left(\delta^{\mu\nu}_{i\phi}\delta^{i\kappa}_{\alpha\beta}n^2 + \delta^{\kappa\mu\nu}_{\phi\alpha\beta}\right)$

Where $\delta^{\dots}_{\dots}$ are the generalized Kroenecker deltas, and $u$ is the four-velocity of the medium under the consideration.

---

ONLY now can we consider what happens if we start boosting. Let us boost into reference frame what is moving with speed $v$ along x-direction.

The boost is given by $\Lambda^\mu_{\nu}=\left(\begin{array} & \gamma & \frac{v}{c}\gamma & 0 & 0 \\ \frac{v}{c}\gamma & \gamma & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{array}\right)$

Where $\gamma=1/\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}$

So in the new reference frame, call it $\bar{S}$, the $\Xi$ - tensor is:

$\bar{\Xi}^{\mu\nu}_{\alpha\beta}=\Lambda^{\mu}_{\mu'}\Lambda^{\nu}_{\nu'}\left(\Lambda^{-1}\right)^{\alpha'}_{\alpha}\left(\Lambda^{-1}\right)^{\beta'}_{\beta}\Xi^{\mu'\nu'}_{\alpha'\beta'}$

---

Results:

Lets see what the dielectric tensor is. For electric displacement we have:

$\left(\begin{array}& \bar{D}^x \\ \bar{D}^y  \\ \bar{D}^z \end{array}\right) = \varepsilon_0 \left(\begin{array}& 
n^2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 
\frac{n^2-\beta^2}{1-\beta^2} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \frac{n^2-\beta^2}{1-\beta^2} \end{array}\right) \left(\begin{array}& \bar{E}^x \\ \bar{E}^y  \\ \bar{E}^z \end{array}\right) + 
c\varepsilon_0 \left(\begin{array}& 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 
-\frac{\beta\left(n^2-1\right)}{1-\beta^2} 
\\ 0 & 
\frac{\beta\left(n^2-1\right)}{1-\beta^2}
 & 0 \end{array}\right) \left(\begin{array}& \bar{B}^x \\ \bar{B}^y  \\ \bar{B}^z \end{array}\right) $

where $\beta=v/c$. For magnetic H-field you have:

$\left(\begin{array}& \bar{H}^x \\ \bar{H}^y  \\ \bar{H}^z \end{array}\right) = c\varepsilon_0 \left(\begin{array}& 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 
-\frac{\beta\left(n^2-1\right)}{1-\beta^2}
\\ 0 & 
\frac{\beta\left(n^2-1\right)}{1-\beta^2}
& 0 \end{array}\right) \left(\begin{array}& \bar{E}^x \\ \bar{E}^y  \\ \bar{E}^z \end{array}\right) + 
\mu_0^{-1} \left(\begin{array}& 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 
\frac{1-n^2\beta^2}{1-\beta^2} 
& 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \frac{1-n^2\beta^2}{1-\beta^2}  \end{array}\right) \left(\begin{array}& \bar{B}^x \\ \bar{B}^y  \\ \bar{B}^z \end{array}\right) $

In such a complex material you will have not just usual plane waves, but many different kinds of waves that can propagate in a very complex fashion, so defining refractive index (just one) will not be possible unless you choose one possible type of waves.

So to answer your question. Refractive index is not a covariant quantity. Once materials start moving their electromagnetic response can change so much that you need rank 4 tensor with 36 different components to fully capture it.

---

EDIT. Fixed few errors. Simpler expressions. Same message

Comment: Can you simplify the final refractive index $n^\prime=\sqrt{\epsilon^\prime \mu^\prime}$, according to your own calculations, to a specific function of $v$ and $n$ for a plane wave moving parallel to $v$ and perpendicular to interface?

Comment: What do you mean by $\epsilon'$ and $\mu'$? I don't have anything like this above. I have four matrices that describe a rather complex material response. What makes you think plane waves are valid solutions in such a medium? They might be, but have you checked it? Also don't forget that your continuity conditions at the interface with such material will be different to what you are used to. This is what I meant by the need to work with Maxwell's equations rather than their simplified versions.

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial and very concise answer. The refractive index is derived from the dielectric function or "constant". This "constant" in general is a tensor of which the elements may depend on frequency and direction of the EM field. To discuss its Lorentz covariant form I have to switch to Lorentz covariant notation and Einstein summation. The electromagnetic field tensor in a medium is $$F'^{\mu\nu} = \epsilon^{\mu\nu}_{\rho\sigma} F^{\rho\sigma}~.$$ Thus in general the "dielectric constant" is a very complex fourth rank Lorentz tensor with elements that are functions of frequency and field orientation.

The tensor for a moving medium is obtained by Lorentz transformation of this fourth rank tensor.

Answer (score -4):

> Is the refractive index an invariant to Lorentz transformations?

No, it's not. The relativistic index of refraction is:

$$n^\prime=\frac{1+v/(nc)}{1/n+v/c}=\frac{n+\frac{v}{c}}{1+n\frac{v}{c}}$$

This refractive index can easily be calculated using the relativistic addition formula. The velocity of the light in the medium is $c/n$ and the velocity of the medium is $v$ WRT the lab observer. Therefore, the relativistic velocity addition implies:

$$w=\frac{c/n+v}{1+v/(nc)} \space ,$$

where $w$ is the speed of light WRT the lab observer. [See this article.](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Light_in_moving_media) The relativistic refractive index is thus calculated to be:

$$n^\prime=\frac{c}{w}=\frac{1+v/(nc)}{1/n+v/c}=\frac{n+\frac{v}{c}}{1+n\frac{v}{c}}$$

Recall that the refractive index is the ratio of the greater velocity ($c$) to the smaller one ($w$).

However, remember that this index of refraction is for when the light travels parallel to the motion direction of the medium and perpendicular to the interface. Calculations are slightly complicated for other directions.

Comment: According to this, as $v/c\to 1$, the refractive index of any object approaches $1$. Curious.

Comment: The author of that article also claims in eq. 19 that $\frac{n+v/c}{1+nv/c}=\tanh\left(n+v/c\right)$, so I'd take this with a grain of salt...

Comment: @ probably_someone Yes, you're right. This is because at speeds close to light speed, the light would always travel at $c$ regardless of the effects of the medium in which the light moves. This means that $n=1$. (It is very similar to the relativistic velocity addition formula)

Comment: @ probably_someone Thanks for notifying me of the errors in the article. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Now the formula doesn't make sense at all. When $v=0$, you're saying that $n'=\frac{1}{n}$, when the refractive index at $v=0$ should be $n$.

Comment: @probably_someone God bless you! I have edited the post again.

Comment: @ Mohammad Javanshiry. You should not try to interpret refractive index like this in SR context. What appears in Maxwell's equations, as linear terms, is permeability and permittivity. You should first derive the transformation laws for them, and only then go to refractive index.

Comment: For example, from here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_formulation_of_classical_electromagnetism it seems clear that magnetization and polarization together form a rank-2 tensor. Thus a material that can be polarized in its rest-frame (has non-unity refractive index), will appear to be magnetizable in a moving reference frame, i.e. it will seem to have non-trivial permeability. Your treatment does not reflect it at all.

Comment: @Cryo My resolution is based on geometry. There can be hundreds of methods to solve a problem. Yet, this does not mean mine is wrong. Other methods must verify my calculation.

Comment: @Mohammad Javanshiry. Your solution is wrong because you are not solving Maxwell's equations, you are trying to extract some understanding from a significantly simplified 'stump' of a solution, without even checking which approximations apply and which don't. See my answer to understand what sort of treatment one has to do to hope to get to the correct solution.

Comment: @probably_someone and other downvoters. The same formula for refractive index is also given by Shen (2004) https://arxiv.org/pdf/physics/0408005.pdf for the case of light travelling parallel to the relative velocity difference. The full derivation from Maxwell's equations and the relativistic transforms of the fields looks ok to me. However I don't understand that $\tanh$ expression.

Comment: When $v=0$, $n'=n$ and when $v \rightarrow c$, $n' \rightarrow 1$, which is what I would expect.

Comment: @ProfRob, have not seen the article, thanks. That does not change the fact that this reply should have been downvoted. The justification provided here was insufficient, and if it agrees with more thorough treatment, it would seem to be a case of luck.

Comment: @ProfRob The paper you quoted computes refractive index as a simple algebraic expression given permittivity and permeability. This only makes sense in a simple medium. Once you have non-trivial electric and magnetic response, that could support several kinds of propagating waves, with different dispersion relations, it is not a good idea to talk about a single refractive index - it is meaningless.

Comment: @Cryo is it correct within those limitations? (Other than the tanh expression which I definitely dont follow).

Comment: @ProfRob, I have not gone through paper thoroughly enough to have a good reply. It makes sense to work with magnetic and electric fields and permittivities/permeabilities when changing reference frames. etc. It could be correct, up to and including section 2. Starting from section 3, I think the paper jumps too far ahead. Refractive index and speed of light in the medium imply propagating waves and dispersion relations have not been established and checked. Ok, they limit the polarization and direction of the supposed propagating wave, but who says it is possible? What if ...

Comment: ... polarization eigenstates are elliptic, so it is not possible to keep linearly polarized wave in this medium at all. Section 3 should be about solving the new Maxwell's equations, and this is not done. So beyond section 2 of the paper I am sceptical. As far as section 2 is concerned, IMHO I gave a better reply above

Comment: @Cryo I'm not not disputing your last point. But for the case of a linearly polarised plane wave travelling in the same direction as the velocity difference between the frames, in a non-dispersive medium, wouldn't that just appear as a linearly polarised plane wave in the other frame of reference?

Comment: @ProfRob, probably yes, maybe not, I did not even see proof that propagating waves would be transversely polarized. Presence of non-trivial magnetic response worries me. There is no point guessing. One can find the answer if one needs it, and the proper way to do it is by solving Maxwell's equations for propagating waves. I am playing Devil's advocate here suggesting what could go wrong :-)