# Roll, Pitch, and Yaw in Micro-Ring Optical Resonators

Tags: optics

I'll remind those who answer that I am neither a physicist nor a physics student. I'm just that (58-year-old) kid who keeps asking, "Why?" Though formulas and equations are welcome, they’re usually not necessary to answer my questions.

Am I correct to assume one must keep an optical micro-ring resonator very stable to maintain resonance? It seems that, if such a resonator were on a turntable, the Sagnac effect would damp the resonance by misaligning the peaks and troughs of circulating waves to cause destructive interference. In the case of a tilt table, I imagine the path of propagation would lengthen, due to additional internal reflection and similarly, introduce destructive interference.

Please let me know if I misunderstand the way circulating light behaves in a micro-ring resonator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is certainly true, that the direct consequence of micro-ring resonators being resonators, is that they are very sensitive to disturbances. That's their point.

One way to look at what happens with micro-resonator when you move it could be that path of light propagation lengthens. One can also represent it as a change in refractive index. [Here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/509014/refraction-and-reflection-in-special-relativity), for example, it is shown that optical properties of a medium, such as glass, change when it is moving (from the point of view of a stationary observer). One way to think about it is that refractive index of a moving piece of glass, from your point of view, is different compared to the stationary piece of glass. Refractive index is directly impacting the resonant properties of the resonator, so it will be detectable in the shift of its response, i.e. it will resonate at different wavelengths as a result of movement (when measured from a stationary laboratory). Apart from refractive index, movement will also affect what happens at the air-dielectric boundary, which would also impact total internal reflection, and hence the optical response of a resonator.