# Relativistic Doppler Effect in a Medium

Tags: special-relativity, doppler-effect

I am trying to find out how our relativistic Doppler effect formula would change taking into account mediums (not just vacuums), since the speed of light can drastically change depending on where the wave is propagating. My original thought was to simply change the value of c in the Doppler formula (within B):

[image]

for B, I would get v/x where x is the speed of light in the medium (taking into account its refractive index). However I feel like it is not that simple, as some sources explicitly explain that this formula only works for B in a vacuum. Keep in mind I am only talking about mediums at rest. I cannot find anything online about this Doppler effect when the speed of light is altered, so I would really appreciate any pointers!

Answer (score 0):

The relativistic Doppler formula requires that an absolute frame of rest be non-sense (hence the symmetry). Once you introduce a medium, there's kind of natural rest frame, so just taking $c \rightarrow c/n$ isn't going to work as $c/n$ is not the speed of causality. ($n$ is an index of reafraction, ofc).

So the best move (imho) is to define your 'rest' frame, $S$, to be the frame of the medium.

In one dimension, consider a photon moving in the $+x$ direction at speed $s$:

$$ s = c/n $$

now make that into a 4-velocity:

$$ u_{\mu} = (\gamma_s c, \gamma_s s) = \gamma_s c(1, 1/n) $$

with

$$\gamma_s = \frac 1 {\sqrt{1-\frac 1 {n^2}}}$$

so:

$$ u_{\mu} =  c\Big(
\frac 1{\sqrt{(1 + \frac 1 n)(1-\frac 1 n)}},
\frac 1 {\sqrt{(n+1)(n-1)}}\Big) $$

(I'm not sure yet if that last one is helpful. We'll find out.)

Transform to a frame moving, $S'$, moving at $v_x = v$:

$$u'_{\mu} = \Big(
\gamma u_t - \beta\gamma u_x,
-\beta\gamma u_t + \gamma u_x
\Big)$$

$$u'_{\mu} = \gamma\Big(
\frac 1{\sqrt{(1 + \frac 1 n)(1-\frac 1 n)}} - 
 \frac {\beta} {\sqrt{(n+1)(n-1)}},
-\frac {\beta}{\sqrt{(1 + \frac 1 n)(1-\frac 1 n)}} +  \frac 1 {\sqrt{(n+1)(n-1)}}
\Big)$$

I don't think this is working. Let's try defining a wave vector in $S$:

$$k_{\mu} = (\omega/c, k/n) = (\omega/c, \frac{\omega/c} n)
= \frac{\omega} c(1, 1/n)$$

That looks more promising:

$$ k'_{\mu} = 
\frac{\omega} c\Big(
\gamma - \beta\gamma/n,
-\beta\gamma + \gamma/n
\Big)
$$

$$ k'_{\mu} = 
\frac{\gamma\omega} c\Big(
1- \beta/n,
-\beta + 1/n
\Big)
$$

So that:

$$ \omega' = \omega\gamma(1-\beta/n) $$

and

$$ k' = \gamma k (\frac 1 n - \beta) $$

...so the wavenumber can go to zero if you move in the photon's rest frame.

Looking at frequency:

$$ \frac{\omega'}{\omega} = \gamma(1-\beta/n)$$

Which, in the form of the normal Doppler shift is:

$$ \frac{\omega'}{\omega} = \sqrt{\frac{(1-\beta/n)^2}{(1+\beta)(1-\beta)}}$$

which doesn't match a velocity substitution form, but when $n\rightarrow 1$, you do recover:

$$ \frac{\omega'}{\omega} = \sqrt{\frac{1-\beta}{1+\beta}}$$

Comment: once you get moving media, I don't think refractive index is quite enough. Polarization in a stationary medium will become, partially magnetization, in a different frame, hence your medium will appear to have non-trivial magnetic response. I think you may need to start with first establishing the laws of wave propagation in a moving media, what happens with polarization of the waves etc, and only then move to Doppler effect

Comment: @Cryo phase is Lorentz invariant.

Comment: Phase of what? Does your moving medium support plane waves with normal linear dispersion relation, or does it support multiple types of waves now?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/509014/refraction-and-reflection-in-special-relativity/509286#509286

Comment: @Cryo Number one rule in relativity is keep it simple. Phase, as in $\phi = \vec k \cdot \vec x - \omega t = k_{\mu}x^{\mu}$ is manifestly a 4-scalar; $k_{\mu}$ is a 4-vector, so it transforms covariantly. I agree it's tricky in 3+1, but the point of (3, 1) is that Lorentz transformation have to work.

Comment: rule number zero is to keep it correct, and rule -1 is to read the question. That last one is for me. You did say that you would be operating out of the rest frame of the medium, which removes all my concerns. So false alarm, apologies

Comment: But, $$ u_{\mu} = (\gamma_s c, \gamma_s s) = \gamma_s c(1, 1/n) $$, is not a four-vector.

Comment: @JerroldFranklin why not? If I write the world line of a photon in a medium and take $dS/d\tau$, what do I get? idk, I haven't done it.